# How to edit a foreign key in many-to-many relationship (Database-first)

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I feel like this is a very simple issue but I can't seem to figure it out..

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 with entity framework 6 (still fairly new to all this).

I have a many-to-many relationship between 2 tables. Here's an illustration:

[image]

I can add zipcodemasks to my countries just fine but I can't seem to edit the reference to an existing one. How would one do this using EF?

Comment: Since you are using Database First you should have an Entity generated for __LinkCountryZipcodeMask__. Then you should be able to get that record using Where() to filter.

Comment: The primary key of LinkCountryZipcodeMask is the composition of the 2 foreign keys countryID and zipcodemaskID. When defined like this, entity framework does not create an entity for LinkCountryZipcodeMask.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing an existing zipcodemask, I just ended up removing it and added a new one. This solved my issue for now.